# Can't find certificate by serial number

Tags: c#, asp.net, x509certificate

I've imported my certificates to Personal -> Certificates.

I use the following lines of code to find my certificate by serial number but I can't:

```
    public X509Certificate2Collection FindCerts(string serialNumber)
    {
        var searchType = X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber;
        var storeName = "MY";

        var certificatesStore = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        certificatesStore.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

        var matchingCertificates = certificatesStore.Certificates.Find(searchType, serialNumber, true);

        certificatesStore.Close();

        return matchingCertificates;
    }
```

Could you please tell me why I can't find my cert even though it is in certificatesStore.Certificates list?

Note: my certs were created by Go Daddy

Comment: Would have added this as a comment, but can't. Just wanted to add copying and pasting even via Notepad doesn't get rid of the special character. You really do need to type it in manually, removing the spaces along the way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've fixed this problem by entering the serial number instead copying from the property window. I don't know why when copying from this window, it contains a strange character on the beginning of the serial number.

Comment: can confirm this issue. There is a character before the serial number in the property window. When copied to VS it is not visible, but its there.

Answer (score 9):

Since I came across this issue too, I tried to make a workaround to be able to copy paste the value from the certmgr.msc

A summary of what I did :

```
// The value below is pasted from certmgr.msc
var sslCertificateSerialNumber="‎47 9f da c4 ad d7 33 a6 4c ad 54 d3 d9 95 67 1c"; 


// Remove all non allowed characters that entered the value while copy/paste
var rgx = new Regex("[^a-fA-F0-9]");
var serial = rgx.Replace(sslCertificateSerialNumber, string.Empty).ToUpper();
```

Now I found the correct certificate with a copy/pasted value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the presence of certificate in machine store, can you try giving the third parameter to Find() as 'false'?

Comment: I've tried to Find() as 'false' already but it doesn't work. When trying to debug, I see my cert in the certificatesStore.Certificates collection: certificatesStore.Certificates[2] is exactly what I want to find.

Comment: Are you able to get any other certificate in the same store or in a different store? Can you try getting a certificate created using a different method (for example, using 'makecert' tool)?

`>makecert -r -len 2048 -a sha256 -n "CN=Test" -sr LocalMachine -sk test_key1 -ss My`

Hope you are giving serial number without any spaces...

Comment: Yes, there're 7 certificates in "MY" store, I'm able to get some of them, the GoDaddy certs cann't be found by using this method.

Comment: By using GetSerialNumberString from this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getserialnumberstring.aspx). I've typed the returned serial number from the pfx file to my above method but it also doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: Does the serial number that you see for the certificate in the collection when you debug and input serial number are same?

Comment: Is finding the certificate by serial number the only way? Have you tried finding the certificate by Issuer name?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate serial number is a binary data sequence which denotes a big int of unlimited length. If you saw the text somewhere, this can mean that either the text was written as serial OR (which is more likely) that you are seeing either Base64- or Base16- encoded binary serial. In the latter case you won't find it in straightforward way - you need to decode the serial and try that way.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to extract are the certificate/s issued by GoDaddy,you may use this:

```
var certificateStore= new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certificates = certificateStore.Certificates;
foreach (var certificate in certificateStore)
            {
                if (certificate.Issuer.Contains("GoDaddy"))
                {
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that serialNumber is uppercase string. I had some problems with finding certificates when sn was in lowercase. Also remove whitespaces if you copy sn from the certificate's details window

Answer (score 0):

If you copy from the windows certificate property window, you may accidentally copy some extra invisible characters across, which will break your serial number search.

See this question for more information:
[X509 store can not find certificate by SerialNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356362/x509-store-can-not-find-certificate-by-serialnumber?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue yesterday and spent a number of hours trying to find out why on earth the existing certificate was not being found. It seems that the Certificates.Find method executes a case-sensitive search. I took the recursive approach using String.Compare.

```
X509Certificate2 storedCert = null;
for (int i = 0; i < store.Certificates.Count; i++)
{
    if (String.Compare(store.Certificates[i].SerialNumber, MySerialNum, true) == 0)
    {
        storedCert = store.Certificates[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find by serial number, starting from the serial as reported by the mmc snap-in, remove all whitespace and uppercase all alphas. Worked for me. This will give you something like...

```
008CC59B72BE954F93F1435F6B86227600
```

As others have said, pay super attention to the "invisible special character" at the start of the string. Copy into and out of notepad to strip it. The same goes for all fields copied out of the cert property window.