# X509 store can not find certificate by SerialNumber

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I need to get a X509 Certificate by Serial Number, I have the serial number and I am looping through them and i see the serial number in the collection I need but it is never found.

Here is my debug code just ot make sure I am seeing the proper serial numbers:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in store.Certificates)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write (cert.SerialNumber + "=" + oauthCertificateFindValue + "<br/>");
                if (cert.SerialNumber == oauthCertificateFindValue)
                {
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br/>FOUND FOUND FOUND<br/>");
                }
            }
```

Here is the output from this code:

```
0091ED5F0CAED6AD52‎‎=0091ED5F0CAED6AD52
3D3233116A894CB244DB359DF99E7862=0091ED5F0CAED6AD52
```

Clearly the first one I loop though matches the serial number but the `if` always fails and what I really need to work based on this serial number also fails:

```
   X509Certificate2Collection certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(x509FindType, oauthCertificateFindValue, false);

   if (certificateCollection.Count == 0)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("An OAuth certificate matching the X509FindType '{0}' and Value '{1}' cannot be found in the local certificate store.", oauthCertificateFindType, oauthCertificateFindValue));
                }

     return certificateCollection[0];
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is nothing looks wrong.. What is `x509FindType`? Did you tried to change it?

Comment: Did you by any chance copy the serial number out of the standard Windows certificate view dialog? I've found a similar issue before where copying from the dialog inserts an invisible character at the beginning of the copied string, causing looks-ups to fail. Check that `oauthCertificateFindValue.Length` is the expected length of the serial number (and probably also that it'd divisible by 2 given that it's expressed as a hex string).

Comment: I got the Serial Number by looping through the certs and outputting them looking for the one in particular I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that there are two invisible characters in the certificate serial number of the certificate you're trying to find, which is why they aren't matching. You should be able to confirm this if you change the output from your `foreach` loop to:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write (string.Format("{0} (Length: {1}) = {2} (Length: {3})<br/>", cert.SerialNumber, cert.SerialNumber.Length oauthCertificateFindValue, oauthCertificateFindValue.Length);
```

You'll most likely see that the values look the same, but their lengths differ (indicating the presence of these invisible characters).

You will need to update your search value to match the certificate's serial number including the invisible characters.

Answer (score 0):

The first `X509Store` you have opened that was not closed yet and from the same you tried to get the certificate which was already read out.

First close the store in code where you are matching the serials and the code where you are reading from store, reopen the store.

Below code worked for me. Just verify once.

```
 private static void CompareCertSerialse()
    {
        string oauthCertificateFindValue = "7C00001851CBFF5E9F563E236F000000001851";

        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in store.Certificates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cert.SerialNumber + "=" + oauthCertificateFindValue);
            if (cert.SerialNumber == oauthCertificateFindValue)
            {
              Console.WriteLine("FOUND FOUND FOUND>");

             //Close the store  
              store.Close();
              GetCert(oauthCertificateFindValue);                     
            }
        }
    }


 private static X509Certificate2 GetCert(string oauthCertificateFindValue)
    {
        //Reopen the store
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        X509Certificate2Collection certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, oauthCertificateFindValue, false);

        if (certificateCollection.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nothing Found");
        }

        return certificateCollection[0];
    }
```